# Configuring Chrome OS as a Wireless Router

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, google-chrome-os

I got the new chromebook plus v2 from samsung, and I wanted to see if I can set up an access point using the chromebook's wifi card and bridge the connection to the chromebook's LTE mobile broadband connection.

I haven't found a way to do it. I saw a [method using hostapd and dnsmasq on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1183669/configuring-linux-as-a-wireless-router-configure-wireless-card-as-ap-on-separat), but I couldn't figure out how to implement either package. The shell provided in Chrome OS developer mode doesn't have a package manager and the Linux VM doesn't seem to support the iw command which is needed for checking AP support.

After installing the iw package on the VM, running iw list as username@penguin returns command not found and running sudo iw list returns nl80211 not found.

Can anyone help in either pointing to documentation or detailing any methods to use a chromebook as a wireless router?